# How to use a regex to validate an iFrame in a Symfony form input?

Tags: php, regex, symfony

In a publishing form, a user can decide to add one or more media, they just need to copy/paste `<iframe>` tags into text fields.

I would like to find a solution to make sure that the user only enters valid `<iframe>` tags in this form.

I'm trying to use an `@Assert\Regex` in my entity, as below, but this doesn't work because no matter what data is entered, it is validated.

I've used the [PHP Live Regex](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ENm) online tool to help me write this regex. On this tool, my regex seems to work well.

- What's wrong with this regex?
- Is using an `@Assert\Regex` in this case a good practice ?

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MediaRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MediaRepository::class)
 */
class Media
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/<iframe[^>]*>\s*<\/iframe>/",
     *     message="Please enter a valid iframe tag"
     * )
     */
    private $iframe;
```

Comment: I feel like it would be better to let the user configure your iframe, but not by typing the whole html tag, which seem.. dangerous.
What about creating an entity Iframe with different properties such as url width height and some options and then use it to create your iframe ?

Comment: This is a good idea ! Unfortunately, this is a school project and the exercise statement says **"users must copy and paste an iframe tag into the field in order to add media."**
I then thought that using a regex is a functional solution, in this case, but I don't understand why `@Assert\Regex` doesn't work.
Thanks for confirming that allowing user input of an iframe is bad practice... ^^

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, the regular expression constraint works when initialized from the FormBuilder, like this :

```
class MediaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('iframe',  TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => new Regex([
                    'pattern' => "/^<iframe[^>]*>\s*<\/iframe>/",
                    'message' => "Please enter a valid iFrame tag",
                ])
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Media::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```